# How would I use a batch file to make a new file in a specified location

Tags: batch-file

While executing a batch file it only adds files to its own directory, I wanted to make it so that it makes the new TXT file to a specified location

```
echo You are very good > you.txt
```

This just makes a text file in the same Dir as the batch file, how would I make it so that it makes the txt file into a specific location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily specify the full path like this:

```
echo You are very good >"YOUR FULL FILE PATH HERE LIKE C:\MYFOLDER\you.txt"
```

Comment: More correctly, `(Echo You are very good) 1> "AbsoluteOrRelativePath\you.txt"` or `1> "AbsoluteOrRelativePath\you.txt" Echo You are very good`